# How to filter child table selected using with clause in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am querying Item using following:

```
$itemdata = Item::with('itemimagedetails')
    ->with('variation')
    ->select('item.id', 'item.cat_id', 'item.item_name', 'item.item_description', 'item.brand', 'item.manufacturer', 'item.country_origin', 'item.ingredient_type', 'item.delivery_time', 'categories.category_name', 'item.category_unit')
    ->join('categories','item.cat_id','=','categories.id')
    ->where('item.id', $request['item_id'])->get()->first();
```

I want to filter variations using planid fetched from user table.

```
$plan = User::where('id', $request['user_id'])
```

I have tried:

```
if (count($itemdata->variation) > 0) {
    $plan = User::where('id', $request['user_id'])->get();

    foreach ($itemdata->variation as $key => $tag_name) {
        if($tag_name == $plan['plan_id']) {
            unset($itemdata->variation[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get an error in the API calls.

Can someone please suggest best approach?

Comment: In your code `$plan` is actually a user model. how does this relate to what you want to do? What is `planid` and how does it fit to your current result. Also replace `->get()->first()` with just `->first()` since that will limit the query itself rather than get the first result from the entire result set.

Comment: also, `User::where('id', ...)->get()`, there should only be one user by 'id', not many, so call `first` instead of `get` and you will have one result or `null`

Comment: in user model there is planid which again defined in variance to show only related variance to user with particular planid

Comment: please share the error in your question

Comment: Why not just set up Eloquent relationships between these models, it will make this query much easier.

Answer (score 0):

try using "having" statement  search it in in laravel docs